# How do I share KMS key across multiple regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

I have already updated the key policy as follows.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "key-default-1",
  "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
              "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_1:root"
          },
          "Action": "kms:*",
          "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
          "Sid": "Give access permission to ACC_2",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
              "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACC_2:root"
          },
          "Action": "kms:*",
          "Resource": "*",
          "Condition": {
              "StringEquals": {
                  "kms:CallerAccount": "ACC_2"
              },
              "ArnEquals": {
                  "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:ACC_2:key/*"
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

When I'm trying to access this key, it gives an error saying

`Specified KMS key [arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:ACC_2:key/mrk-KEY_ID] does not exist, is not enabled or you do not have permissions to access it.`

Does my key policy was wrong? What am I missing?

Please note that the key was shared from `us-east-1` region to `us-east-2` region.

I want to use this shared KMS key to copy another shared database.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "shared", there is no such thing!? You cannot just use a KMS key cross region, you need to set up multi-region keys: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/multi-region-keys-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

1. first create a key marked as multi-region in us-east-1
2. go to us-east-2 and replicate the key to us-east-2